# Customize search results and facets in Liferay 7.1

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

this is my first question, thanks in advance.

I am trying to customize the liferay results portlet and facets, with custom results. I need to filter the results once the search is launched, and remove the results that do not have layoutId :

with->
layoutIds = journalContentSearchLocalService.getLayoutIds(groupId,false,articleIdResult);

I´m doing this in a jsp fragment, but i think that it´s not correct.

I have been searching and i think the correct way is to modify the java class with the action, for example with acction coomand hook, is this correct?

Please, can you explain me the correct way to modify this functionalities?

Regards!!

[image: Search]

Answer (score 0):

ok. it looks you want  result of journalarticle having display page is set. in that case, you need to look for JournalarticleModelPreFiltercontributor component extension or journalarticlepostprocessor if you are using legacy search api. when article gets indexed layoutuuid field is also indexed for each article. that field will have value if display page is set for specific web content or article.

So, you can use any of the above mentioned way to add check that this field should not be empty as search term. which will filter your result in request itself. instead adding  overhead on result as later filtering in jsp.